# Are there "well-behaved" functions which iterate infinitely without repeating while also being bounded?

Tags: functions, chaos-theory, iterated-function-system

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53lBKCBrENY#t=8m58s) the presenter shows that for strictly increasing functions $f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \implies f(x)=x$ because when you iterate $f$ it either increases forever or decreases forever. We cannot solve $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ completely in general using $f(x)=x$ for other functions e.g. $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ because when you iterate them you might get a loop.

In this example, $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ forms a loop when you iterate the point $(1,-1)$.

Are there "well-behaved functions" (e.g. polynomials, trig functions, etc, the usual suspects) which can be iterated infinitely such that the values are both bounded and aperiodic?

Comment: Lots of them. How about $e^{-x^{2}}$, for example.

Comment: $f(x)=1+x/2$ has only one fixed point $2$ under iteration. No other finite orbits and all orbits converge to $2$.